# CheckedListBox allowing only one item to be checked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

In my `CheckedListBox` app I want to allow only a single item to be checked.

I have these properties already set

```
checkOnClick = true;
SelectionMode = One;
```

Any advise will be appreciated

Comment: When the user clicks on the listbox, uncheck the other items.

Comment: would a grouping of radio buttons not suit things better?

Comment: First [google](https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=de&rlz=1G1ACAW_DEDE443&q=CheckListBox++only+one+item&oq=CheckListBox++only+one+item&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=igoogle.3...67628.71513.0.71707.17.5.1.11.0.0.261.587.3j1j1.5.0...0.0.4BbfKlsCIQk) hit: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/5333cdf2-a669-467c-99ae-1530e91da43a/

Comment: It seems CheckedListBox inherits SelectionMode from ListBox, but ignores that property.

Comment: @akatakritos Selection is different and checking is different. You can have something selected but not checked.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

uncheck all other items in ItemCheck event as below :

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
      for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
        if (ix != e.Index) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought there must have been a simple property that would do.

Comment: even simpler is radio buttons, customers are used to radiobuttons being only one choice and checkboxes being multiple choice, be very careful before you force changes on them like this

Comment: @Ahmed as RhysW said you are better off using radio button...but if you have to use checkboxes then this way would work..

Comment: @Sam1 Surely that would have been better but in this case I am across an exceptional different scenario where this approach fits best.

Comment: @Ahmed as I said if you have to then there is no reason not to use it :)

Answer (score 9):

the best way to do this is like this:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[0], false);
        checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
    }
}
```

no looping is always better.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this by **checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged** Event.

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int idx = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        for(int i=0;i<checkedListBox1.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            if(i != idx)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
            
    }
```