# Why does Visual Studio make available an invalid selection in the property page?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-select, checkedlistbox

I want to cause a CheckedListBox to only allow one selection, and was investigating its Property page/pane/panel to see if there was a likely property for that. I saw "SelectionMode", which contains the following options in its dropdown:

```
One
MultiSimple
MultiExtended
```

I selected "MultiSimple" to see what the synopsis text at the bottom of the Property pane would tell me about it. Instead of being edified, though, I got this fingerwag:

[image]

Why does Visual Studio pull a Lucy Van Pelt on me, pulling away the "football" as I try to "kick it"? If the property is not available for the control, don't populate the dropdown with it!

### UPDATE

BTW, Zaki's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553323/checkedlistbox-alllowing-only-one-item-to-be-checked) gives me what I need to limit selection to 1; I still think some Redmondian should explain himself on this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control `CheckedListBox` does not support "multiple-selection" which is indicated in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode.aspx) under the heading *Remarks* where it says:

> The SelectionMode property determines whether one item in the list box
>   can be selected or no items can be selected. For CheckedListBox
>   objects, multiple selection is not supported. You can set the mode to
>   one item or no items.

Apparently this fact has not been implemented in the design-time UI of the property sheet, which then allows you to choose inappropriate values, causing the error message.

IMHO -- I think your *Lucy Van Pelt* comparison is very appropriate in this case.