# Choose 1 checkbox out of 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got several checkbox, but I only want the the text "New Desktop" and "New Laptop" can only choose 1 out of 2. I hope it could be done in C#.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Service1" runat="server" 
                     Width="251px" >
                 <%--onselectedindexchanged="checkBox1_CheckedChanged"--%>
                    <asp:ListItem text="New Login ID & Email Address" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem text="New Desktop" Value="2" oncheckedchanged="checkBox1_CheckedChanged" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem text="New Notebook" Value="3" oncheckedchanged="checkBox2_CheckedChanged"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem text="New Mouse"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem text="New Keyboard"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem text="New Printer"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>


//.cs pages
protected void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Service1.Items[2].Selected == true)
            {
                Service1.Items[3].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
protected void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Service1.Items[3].Selected == true)
            {
                Service1.Items[2].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this could help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10553349/6538824

Comment: Thank Giorgi, because I'm still a begginer I dont really understand the way it write.

Comment: code you give above is not working?

Comment: yes, I try it for days and it did not respond on the page

Comment: @GiorgiKhorguani

Comment: @Johnny - It just un-checks all the check boxes except the one which was selected. That happens on checkbox checked event.

Comment: You can make use of `SelectedIndexChange` event handler of checkBoxList and set `postBack=true` , so whenever user check/uncheck a checkbox the event will be fired, there you can check which one is checked or not and can done your requirements.

Comment: why you are not using a Radio Button Control?

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you one example below but still this may not be a feasible way. You need to add CheckedChanged event to each CheckBox  to remove check from other CheckBoxes

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     if(CheckBox1.Checked)
     {
          CheckBox2.Checked =false;
          CheckBox3.Checked =false;
          CheckBox4.Checked =false;
      }
}
```

You should repeat the above evevt for CheckBox2 , CheckBox3 and so on. You can extend it as per your requirement.

But in this scenario I would recommend you to use the ASP.NET Radio Button Control. Please refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on Radio Button Control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnSelectedIndexChanged event for CheckBoxList with AutoPostBack="True" so your control send request to server and selection chenged event will be call
I.e : For design

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Service1" runat="server" Width="251px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Service1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="New Login ID & Email Address"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="New Desktop" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="New Notebook" Value="3" ></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="New Mouse"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="New Keyboard"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="New Printer"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and in code: 'li' have all selected item and as per your requirement "New Desktop" and "New Laptop" only choose 1 out of 2 .

```
protected void Service1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxList li = (CheckBoxList)sender;
            foreach (ListItem l in li.Items)
            {
                if (l.Value == "2")
                {
                    if (l.Selected)
                    {
                        Service1.Items[2].Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Service1.Items[2].Enabled = true;
                    }

                }
                else if (l.Value == "3")
                {
                    if (l.Selected)
                    {
                        Service1.Items[1].Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Service1.Items[1].Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```